# How can I make the loop item in a new line not in one line

Tags: vb.net

I have a code to display data from the database into a label. All of the data is displaying in one line but I want to make each row of data display in a new line.
I'm using VB.Net

Aspx.vb

```
Sub ResourceName_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
Try
  Dim LanguageName As String = vbNullString
  Dim LangNameList As String = vbNullString
  Dim LangWrittenList As String = vbNullString
  Dim LangSpokenList As String = vbNullString
  Dim WrittenRate As String = vbNullString
  Dim SpokenRate As String = vbNullString


  lblLanguageName.Text = ""
  lblLanguageWritten.Text = ""
  lblLanguageSpoken.Text = ""

   attPage.SQLQuery = DC.Data_TechnicalResource("12",chkResourceName1.SelectedValue)

   DS = DA.GetSQLDataset(attPage.SQLQuery)

        If DS IsNot Nothing AndAlso DS.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then
          For Each dr In DS.Tables(0).Rows
                LanguageName = dr("LanguageName").ToString
                WrittenRate = dr("WrittenLevel").ToString
                SpokenRate = dr("SpokenLevel").ToString
                If cnt <> 0 Then
                    LangNameList = LangNameList + LanguageName
                    LangWrittenList = LangWrittenList + WrittenRate
                    LangSpokenList = LangSpokenList + SpokenRate
                Else
                    LangNameList = LanguageName
                    LangWrittenList = WrittenRate
                    LangSpokenList = SpokenRate
                End If
                cnt = cnt + 1
            Next

        End If
        lblLanguageName.Text = LangNameList
        lblLanguageWritten.Text = LangWrittenList
        lblLanguageSpoken.Text = LangSpokenList
```

The output is as below

```
Bahasa MalaysiaEnglishTamil          10,10,4     10,10,4
```

I want the output should be like this

```
Bahasa Malaysia          10           10

English                  10           10

Tamil                    4             4
```

Anyone can help me to do this ? I would appreciate it. Thank you.

Comment: Unless you have a very small number of records, the better way to handle this would be to use `StringBuilders` rather than `Strings`.  You can then call `AppendLine` and that will handle the line break as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not inserting a new line anywhere in your code, to do that change your if block code to this

```
            If cnt <> 0 Then
                LangNameList = LangNameList + vbNewLine + LanguageName
                LangWrittenList = LangWrittenList + vbNewLine + WrittenRate
                LangSpokenList = LangSpokenList + vbNewLine + SpokenRate
            Else
                LangNameList = LanguageName
                LangWrittenList = WrittenRate
                LangSpokenList = SpokenRate
            End If
```

So your entire code should be like this:

```
Sub ResourceName_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
Try
  Dim LanguageName As String = vbNullString
  Dim LangNameList As String = vbNullString
  Dim LangWrittenList As String = vbNullString
  Dim LangSpokenList As String = vbNullString
  Dim WrittenRate As String = vbNullString
  Dim SpokenRate As String = vbNullString


  lblLanguageName.Text = ""
  lblLanguageWritten.Text = ""
  lblLanguageSpoken.Text = ""

   attPage.SQLQuery = DC.Data_TechnicalResource("12",chkResourceName1.SelectedValue)

   DS = DA.GetSQLDataset(attPage.SQLQuery)

    If DS IsNot Nothing AndAlso DS.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then
      For Each dr In DS.Tables(0).Rows
            LanguageName = dr("LanguageName").ToString
            WrittenRate = dr("WrittenLevel").ToString
            SpokenRate = dr("SpokenLevel").ToString
            If cnt <> 0 Then
                LangNameList = LangNameList + vbNewLine + LanguageName
                LangWrittenList = LangWrittenList + vbNewLine + WrittenRate
                LangSpokenList = LangSpokenList + vbNewLine + SpokenRate
            Else
                LangNameList = LanguageName
                LangWrittenList = WrittenRate
                LangSpokenList = SpokenRate
            End If
            cnt = cnt + 1
        Next

    End If
    lblLanguageName.Text = LangNameList
    lblLanguageWritten.Text = LangWrittenList
    lblLanguageSpoken.Text = LangSpokenList
```

Comment: It's not working. It does not go to a new line but it just make the data have a space in between something like this   BahasaMalaysia     Tamil      English

Comment: @Shasha are you using a label?, then set the autosize property of the label to false, then size it appropriately

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub ResourceName_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
Try
  Dim LanguageName As String = vbNullString
  Dim LangNameList As String = vbNullString
  Dim LangWrittenList As String = vbNullString
  Dim LangSpokenList As String = vbNullString
  Dim WrittenRate As String = vbNullString
  Dim SpokenRate As String = vbNullString


  lblLanguageName.Text = ""
  lblLanguageWritten.Text = ""
  lblLanguageSpoken.Text = ""

   attPage.SQLQuery = DC.Data_TechnicalResource("12",chkResourceName1.SelectedValue)

   DS = DA.GetSQLDataset(attPage.SQLQuery)

        If DS IsNot Nothing AndAlso DS.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then
          For Each dr In DS.Tables(0).Rows
                LanguageName = dr("LanguageName").ToString
                WrittenRate = dr("WrittenLevel").ToString
                SpokenRate = dr("SpokenLevel").ToString
                If cnt <> 0 Then
                    LangNameList = LangNameList + LanguageName
                    LangWrittenList = LangWrittenList + WrittenRate
                    LangSpokenList = LangSpokenList + SpokenRate
                Else
                    LangNameList = LanguageName
                    LangWrittenList = WrittenRate
                    LangSpokenList = SpokenRate
                End If
                cnt = cnt + 1
            Next

        End If
        lblLanguageName.Text = LangNameList
        lblLanguageWritten.Text = LangWrittenList
        lblLanguageSpoken.Text = LangSpokenList
```

You are appending the values to variable **LangNameList**

```
If cnt <> 0 Then
                        LangNameList = LangNameList + LanguageName
                        LangWrittenList = LangWrittenList + WrittenRate
                        LangSpokenList = LangSpokenList + SpokenRate
```

In this step you are appending the valeus.
that means

Ds table contains a list of values and you had assigned the values from table column  **dr("LanguageName")** to **LanguageName** variable 
**LanguageName = dr("LanguageName").ToString**

```
 If cnt <> 0 Then
```

don't append the value

try to print

```
  For Each dr In DS.Tables(0).Rows
                    LanguageName = dr("LanguageName").ToString
                    WrittenRate = dr("WrittenLevel").ToString
                    SpokenRate = dr("SpokenLevel").ToString
                    If cnt <> 0 Then
LangNameList = LangNameList + vbNewLine + LanguageName
            LangWrittenList = LangWrittenList + vbNewLine + WrittenRate
            LangSpokenList = LangSpokenList + vbNewLine + SpokenRate
                    Else
                        LangNameList = LanguageName
                        LangWrittenList = WrittenRate
                        LangSpokenList = SpokenRate
                    End If
                    cnt = cnt + 1
                Next
```

Comment: It's not working. It does not go to a new line but it just make the data have a space in between something like this   BahasaMalaysia     Tamil      English